# Hide a Preference-item depending on the state (enabled/disabled) of another Preference in PreferenceScreen

Tags: android, androidx, android-preferences, preferencescreen

I'm creating a settings screen, and I have a few settings items:
`SwitchPreferenceCompat` and my `CustomPreference`.

I need the **СustomPreference to disappear(hide)** when the **SwitchPreferenceCompat is turned off** and appear(show) when the SwitchPreferenceCompat is turned on.

Out of the box, only the "dependency" mechanism is available by specifying the "dependency" attribute for some Preferences, which only disables/enables items, and I need to change visibility.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

create customPreference and override onDependencyChanged().

```
package com.paul.ttcapp.p9988030.helper.ui;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.preference.EditTextPreference;
import androidx.preference.Preference;

public class PaulEditTextPreference extends EditTextPreference {
    public PaulEditTextPreference(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    public PaulEditTextPreference(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public PaulEditTextPreference(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public PaulEditTextPreference(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDependencyChanged(@NonNull Preference dependency, boolean disableDependent) {
        // If the corresponding dependency is disabled, disable (hide) this setting as well.
        setVisible(!disableDependent);
        super.onDependencyChanged(dependency, disableDependent);
    }
}
```